# Change Enter for Tab

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, key-events

I need to make the Enter key as Tab, changing the focus of the controls.
I tried several methods of javascript and it worked well... but in some ModalPopupExtender when i click in enter, it closes the PopUp, or in other cases that have a gridview with TextBox inside, by clicking enter it also closes a PopUp or generates a postback.
Someone have any solutions?
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix the problem with this code in Page_load:

```
GridView.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", "if(event.keyCode==13)return false;");
```

Thanks!